# How to draw an O in the Fontforge?

Tags: fonts, inkscape, fontforge

I am making my Custom Font from the software called Fontforge. I import my fonts from Inkscape into Fontforge and every letter were fine but when I added the O (Capital O) letter, it doesn't have the hole.

[Image of the letter editing screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHfcY.png)

[The image of O in the main screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBPts.png)

Answer (score 1):

In Inkscape (current version) switch to the node tool, select the O, select a node in the inner ring, and do Path > Reverse. This will reverse the direction of the subpath and the hole should become visible in Fontforge.